# How to create a NotesRichtext item that is computed for display?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I know this is a common problem, and I tried a few solutions already, but the problem I have right now with my current code is that even though the attachments show in the computed for display field, I get the error "Note Item not Found" when I try to open them.

The form is built with two fields, in a programmable table that displays the editable one or the computed for display one.

The trick I found with Google's help was to delete the computed for display item in the `queryopen` event, so Notes regenerates the cfd item when opening the document.  Visually, this works, as I see the text and attachments, but the attachments can't be opened.

Here is the code that removes the item in the QueryOpen of the form:

```
...
Set item = doc.GetFirstItem("dspDescription")
If Not item Is Nothing Then Call item.Remove()
...
```

Has anyone successfully achieved that functionality? Is there another way of doing this?  I already tried with subforms, and because of the way the application is built, I need to be able to switch from editable to read only on the flick of a radio button, so subforms are out of the question as they can't be displayed dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you simple put the richtext item in a controlled access section and make that section editable / not editable with a computed for display formula. Select "always expand" and hide the section title, so that nobody can collapse it, et voila.

Regarding your comment: With this properties:

[image: Section Properties][image]

for this section in designer:

[image: section in designer]

You get this result:

[image]

You see: No twisty, no "visible" section

Comment: Torsten,  this is a nice idea, but it seems that the twisty always shows up.  The UI won't be cute, but at least that works as intended.

Comment: check out my added information for making the twisty invisible

Comment: After 25+ years in Notes development, I didn't know hiding the section would only hide the "twisty" line!!!  That is great and makes the UI very nice as it doesn't show any twisties